# Laravel: Add nested properties to collections

Tags: laravel, collections

In this example a have one blog that have multiple posts.

How can I add elements to a collection and keep everything a collection:

```
$post = collect(['title' => 'Hello', 'content' => 'world']);
$blog->posts->push($post);
```

And then access it with `$blog->posts` but instead I have to access it with `$blog['posts']`.

I have tried:

```
// First way
$blog = collect(['posts']);
$blog->posts->push($post);

// Second way
$blog = collect();
$blog->put('posts' [$post]);

// Third way
$blog = collect();
$blog->put('posts', collect([]));
$blog->posts->push($post);
```

Comment: A collection is a set of (in your case) blogs, and not one blog. The same goes for articles. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ya is this on the front end?

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed I have tried to clarify my question. The important part is how to make `posts` an collection so I can access it like so: `->posts` instead of `['posts']`

Comment: Laravel collections have a [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge) method, however the more pressing question here is what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Cudos could you share a full example of the code to clarify where `$blog` and `$post` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to append new `Article` to the blog's articles.

In this case you have to do the following, in the below example:

```
    $blog = Blog::find(1);

    dump($blog->articles); // Two items retrieved


    // New article
    $newArticle = new Article([
        'title' => 'Article Three',
        'content' => 'Article Three',
    ]);


    // Prepend to articles as a collection
    $blog->articles->prepend($newArticle);
    
    // Save it into DB [If you want]
    // $blog->articles()->save($newArticle);

    dd($blog->articles); // The collection updated with the new item.
```